# How to set Infinite loop slideshow on tumblr header

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, tumblr-themes

I want my slideshow header (on Tumblr theme) to loop infinitely on it's on without having to click the next arrows Please help.
Code below

```
var interval = undefined;
$(document).ready(function() {
  interval = setInterval(getNext, 3000);
  $("a#next").on('click', getNext);
  $("a#prev").on('click', getPrev);
});

function getNext() {
  var $curr = $("#slides .slides:visible"),
      $next = ($curr.next().length) ? $curr.next() : $("#slides .slides").first();
  transition($curr, $next);
}

function getPrev() {
  var $curr = $("#slides .slides:visible"),
      $next = ($curr.prev().length) ? $curr.prev() : $("#slides .slides").last();
  transition($curr, $next);
}

function transition($curr, $next) {
  clearInterval(interval);
  $next.css("z-index", 8).fadeIn("medium", function() {
    $curr.fadeOut().css("z-index", 0);
    $next.css("z-index", 7);
  });
}
```

Comment: Add the setInterval call to the last line of getNext as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the line

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

in the `transition()` function.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/8wsa9yva/)

Comment: In ```$(document).ready()``` you set the intervalled execution of ```getNext()``` via ```interval = setInterval(getNext, 3000);```. But on the first call to ```getNext()``` it in it's turn calls ```transition()``` which disables the interval with ```clearInterval(interval);```. Removing ```clearInterval(interval);``` will let it run infinitely.

Comment: @dekkard could you please repost the above code with the edits. Thank you.

Comment: Also, as @dekkard's JSFiddle shows; you can just declare `interval` with `var interval;`, rather than setting to it to `undefined`.